# Is it possible to have a valid sub-subdomain with a wildcard certificate?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Say I have the following domain:

```
example.com
```

I have a Wildcard SSL certificate for this domain. Subdomains like `test.example.com` validate properly. However, when I try to use a domain like `demo.test.example.com`, I get an error message in all major browsers:

```
demo.test.example.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.example.com , example.com
```

Is it possible to use a wildcard certificate for a "sub-subdomain"?

Comment: Quick answer: No. This question might be better asked on http://serverfault.com/ though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you've already verified that you can't! Here's why:

From: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt

> Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to
>   match any single domain name
>   component or component fragment. E.g.,
>   `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com matches` `foo.com`
>   but not `bar.com`.

Answer (score 7):

The standards don't allow a wildcard to work on multiple levels. However, you can put the specific multilevel subdomain in as a Subject Alternative Name in the wildcard certificate and it will work. Some certificate providers (like DigiCert) allow this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use wildcards. But they only extend to that level of subdomain.

`*.example.com` works for `test.example.com` but not for `demo.test.example.com`.

You would have to specify `*.*.example.com` in the certificate. I'm not sure this would continue working with `test.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could specify the following alternative names in the certificate and then it should work:

```
example.com
*.example.com
*.*.example.com
```

I don't know if there are certificate authorities that provide such certificates.

Comment: Could the 3 downvoters please explain why this is not a useful answer? It seems correct to me from a technical standpoint, at least when RFC 2818 is implemented correctly! Also he has a good point of saing, that certain CAs might not issue multilevel wildcard certificates (although some offer them, even several levels down - digicert used to promote this for example)

Comment: Not a downvoter, but having tried this to create a `*.local, *.*.local` certificate with openssl, this doesn't appear to work in practice. Chrome complains that the "The server could not prove that it is **x.y.local**; its security certificate is from ***.local**". However, regenerating the certificate with `*.local, *.y.local` does work.